# accessing to json property without loop php

Tags: php, json

i'm using PHP and i want to get some date from a json FILE ,
this what i have this file

```
{
"Contacts": [{
    "nataliya.mayk@ut-gr.com": {
        "ContactID": "3367870013932183",
        "First Name": "",
        "Last Name": "maydanyuk",
        "Title": "",
        "full Name": "maydanyuk",
        "Mobile": "",
        "num": 0,
        "num2": 200
    }
}, {
    "sebsfsgilbedsdfsdrt045@orsfsefange.fr": {
        "ContactID": "336787000013037828",
        "First Name": "J\u00e9r\u00f4me",
        "Last Name": "Sommet",
        "Title": "Directeur Commeqsdqdrcial Retail France, membre du CODIR",
        "full Name": "J\u00e9r\u00f4me Sommet",
        "Mobile": "",
        "num": 6,
        "num2": 1600
    }
 }]
}
```

so i should first use

```
$str = file_get_contents('/theFileThatContainsJSON.json');
```

now i want to access to the the ContactID Of email nataliya.mayk@ut-gr.com , how can i do it ?, i want not to to use loops , because the file will be too big.
i want something like that

```
echo $str->Contacts->nataliya.mayk@ut-gr.com->ContactID ;
```

or

```
echo $str['Contacts']['nataliya.mayk@ut-gr.com']['ContactID'] ;
```

i tried all of them but not working , as i said before i want to access directly , because i want to get infromations for specific mail .
thanks
this is not working also

```
why this is not working , i used the same format
```

$str = file_get_contents('http://freelance-day.eu/zohocontacts.json');

```
    $array = json_decode($str, true);

    echo $array['Contacts'][0]['frejus@autoecole-inris.com']['ContactID'];
```

Comment: your json is not valid check here:https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: your JSON seems to be invalid?!

Comment: i got " Valid JSON " , maybe you forget to copy the last } out of the box

Comment: The JSON is valid, but OP forgot to add the last curly bracket to his code snippet. The two answers are both correct, so I think OP didn't decode his string first.

Comment: Php does not automatically parse the file contents as a json string, you need to call for example json_decode() to parse it. Then you can access the resulting object as you need. Look up the documentation of json_decode for detailed information.

Comment: why this is not working , i used the same format
$str = file_get_contents('http://freelance-day.eu/zohocontacts.json');

        $array = json_decode($str, true);
        
        echo $array['Contacts'][0]['frejus@autoecole-inris.com']['ContactID'];

Comment: @MaherSammoudi  you need to decode json data and then apply loop on it and get desired result

Answer (score 0):

Try to decode the JSON and structure

```
 $str = file_get_contents('/theFileThatContainsJSON.json');
$str_arr = json_decode($str, true);

echo $str_arr['Contacts']['nataliya.mayk@ut-gr.com']['ContactID']
```

Comment: why this is not working , i used the same format
$str = file_get_contents('http://freelance-day.eu/zohocontacts.json');

        $array = json_decode($str, true);
        
        echo $array['Contacts'][0]['frejus@autoecole-inris.com']['ContactID'];

Comment: In Contacts[0], there no key like "frejus@autoecole-inris.com". The only key it has is "nataliya.mayk@ut-gr.com"

Comment: how can i access to frejus@autoecole-inris.com and get his ContactID

Comment: You need to go for the loop.